# What is the maximum dimension of a commutative subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{R})?$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\mathcal{A}\subset M_n(\mathbb{R})$ be a commuttative subalgebra of square matrices. What is the maximum dimension $m$ such an algebra can have? Since $\mathbb{D}$ has dimension $n$ and it is commuttative, it follows $m \geq n.$

Comment: One point is that if the elements of $\mathcal A$ are diagonalizable, then the fact that they commute means that they are *simultaneously* diagonalizable, which means that the dimension of the subalgebra is at most $n$

Comment: See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/29089/34894). Apparently, the answer is $1 + \lfloor n^2/4 \rfloor$.